# Need a regex that does not care if less than 6 characters are entered

Tags: javascript, regex, forms, validation

I have this regex that cause my validation message to fire because it requires 6 characters. I need a Regex that allows any amount of characters:

```
var unFieldRegEx = /^(?=.*[a-zA-Z\d])(\w|[\.\@\-\?\,\&\''\/\_\""]){6,}$/;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var unFieldRegEx = /^(?=.*[a-zA-Z\d])(\w|[\.\@\-\?\,\&\''\/\_\""])*$/;
```

should do it (remove the length specifier @ the end and replace with a *)

Answer (score 2):

change {6,} to * for 0 or more characters.  Change it to + for 1 or more characters.